# MySQL триггер на update

Tags: mysql, триггер

Здравствуйте, мудрые программисты, помогите правильно составить триггер. Есть сайт вопросов и ответов, на нем перечень всех вопросов и напротив каждого
 количество ответов, вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целях оптимизации, чтобы не вызывать постоянно MySQL функцию `COUNT(*)` решено хранить готовые расчеты этого показателя (с помощью триггеров) в отдельной таблице `cnt_answ`, вот таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Триггеры на события `insert` и `delete` я написать смог, а как правильно написать триггер на `update`, в случае если например администратор захочет переместить ответ из одного вопроса в другой, после чего поле `cnt_answ` одного вопроса нужно увеличить на 1, а поле другого уменьшить на 1, пока получилось написать вот так:

```
UPDATE cnt_answ SET cnt_answ=IF(NEW.id_questions!=OLD.id_questions,cnt_answ-1,cnt_answ) WHERE id_quest=OLD.id_questions;
UPDATE cnt_answ SET cnt_answ=IF(NEW.id_questions!=OLD.id_questions,cnt_answ+1,cnt_answ) WHERE id_quest=NEW.id_questions;
```

Но этот код будет обращаться к таблице `cnt_answ` всегда, даже когда я не переношу ответ в другой вопрос, а только правлю текст ответа (поле `text_answer`), вот скриншот таблицы ответов: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы чтобы триггер срабатывал только если было изменено поле id_questions таблицы ответов, что-то вроде:

```
IF(NEW.id_questions!=OLD.id_questions)  UPDATE cnt_answ SET cnt_answ.....
```

Ка это сделать?

Comment: Ну вот прямо как вы и написали `IF NEW.id_questions!=OLD.id_questions THEN update ...; END IF;` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, почему-то выдает ошибку. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LqUS/JeXodVDFe Чтобы выяснить причину упростил запрос и сделал так `IF(1!=2) THEN SELECT 'yes'; END IF;` всё равно ошибка: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KdSt/TSupGD9tv

Comment: `IF` это конструкция языка хранимых процедур MySQL, а не SQL запросов. и может использоваться только внутри тригеров и других хранимых процедур. так что не надо упрощать и пытаться выполнить это отдельно от хранимой процедуры (триггера)

Comment: @Mike благодарю, а почему выдает ошибку и тогда когда добавляю её в триггер? вот такую: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LqUS/JeXodVDFe ?

Comment: @Mike всё, разобрался, нужно было обернуть код ещё в BEGIN и END, спасибо Майк, не первый раз выручаешь.

Comment: @Mike есть электронный кошелек?